# Query that will match a non-unique id if there is data in two separate columns across multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to extract data from a single table. What I need a query that will match an id (non-unique) if there is data in two separate columns across multiple rows. Here is an example of the data.

```
+---------+---------------+-----------+
|     id  |  Drivers      | Brands    |
+---------+---------------+-----------+
|    1    |               |  Brands   |
|    2    |   Drivers     |           | 
|    3    |   Drivers     |           | 
|    1    |   Drivers     |           | 
|    4    |               | Brands    | 
|    2    |   Drivers     |           | 
|    3    |               | Brands    | 
|    4    |               | Brands    | 
+---------+---------------+-----------+
```

Id 1 and 3 are the only rows that contain values in both Drivers and Brands. This is the data I need.

Few things about the data:

- There will never be a row with both Drivers and Brands.
- Its possible an id will have multiple rows with just Driver or just Brands (cant use count to determine a match).

Comment: So the result you want is 1 and 3?

Comment: Correct. Id 1 and 3 is what I want. 1 and 3 are the only ids with values in both Drivers and Brands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP BY`. Use the `HAVING` clause to return ID's that have both driver and brand values:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(drivers) > 0 and count(brands) > 0
```

Alternatively, use `INTERSECT`:

```
select id from tablename where drivers is not null
intersect
select id from tablename where brands is not null
```

`INTERSECT` returns the two selects' common rows, and removes duplicates.

Comment: Wow, that was way easier than I expected. This did the trick.

Comment: Just for fun I did a performance comparison of the above queries and also the join version from the other answer. (Added a few thousands rows of data.) With no indexes at all, the GROUP BY query was the best one. With proper indexes INTERSECT outperformed the other two. However, I didn't use Postgresql here.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it for you:

```
select
    d.id
from
    (select distinct id from the_table where Drivers is not null) as d
    inner join (select distinct id from the_table where Brands is not null) as b
        on b.id=d.id;
```